# Modify POP3 account properties in registry

Tags: batch-file, outlook, registry

I want to modify a registry valur using a batch file. I know how to do it using a .reg file but I need to do it using a batch file as there are some more commands in the batch file.

So, I want to change the following value:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000004]

"POP3 Server"=hex:31,00,39,00,32,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,30,00,\
  30,00,00,00
```

Any idea?

Comment: To modify the registry via batch file you can use [reg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) (to provide the value directly) or [regedit.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) (to pass over a registry file).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify the POP3 server name? You should not do that directly in the registry -

- "15" above is for Outlook 2013, so no other version of Outlook will
  work
- "Outlook" above represents the profile name. What if the user has a different profile name?
- "9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676" is the profile section GUID. It is different on each machine.
- 4 is the account id. Also different on different machines.

You need to use either [IOlkAccountManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960327.aspx) API (C++ or Delphi only - you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) if you click the IOlkAccountManager button) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author - any language) - its [RDOPOPAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm#RDOPOP3Account) object explicitly exposes the POP3 server name:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.Logon("YourProfileName")
 set Accounts = Session.Accounts
 for each Account in Accounts
   if Account.AccountType = 0 Then 'atPOP3
     'MsgBox "POP3 server for account " & Account.Name & ": " & Account.POP3_Server
     if Account.POP3_Server = "server1.com" Then
       Account.POP3_Server = "server2.com"
       Account.Save
     End If
   end if 
 next
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is that my knowledge is very limited so I cannot apply what you have written. I am a novice.
therefore I prefer the batch file solution

Comment: The code above will run from a standalone VBS file.